# How to unzip file in ios

Tags: ios, app-store, unzip, ssziparchive

I try to download contents from App store, I download it successfully, now I try to unzip the downloaded file using SSZipArchive. my content file contains video file. (This is the way I upload content file to App Store [steps I did](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_and_Creating_App_Store_Hosted_Content_for_iOS_6_In-App_Purchases)

Here is my code to unzip

```
NSString *zipPath = @"/private/var/mobile/Applications/1433FA1B-24FA-4E39-BB57-80569ECBCBAB/Library/Caches/7AD5C113-253D-4F34-8030-612FFE4347E1.zip";

NSString *outputPath = [self _cachesPath:@"Regular"];

[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:outputPath delegate:self];

NSString *testPath = [outputPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"videofile.mp4"];

bool fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:testPath];

if (fileExists)
{
     NSLog(@"file exists");
}
else
{
     NSLog(@"file not exists");
}
```

always I got file file not exists. How can I get the video file?

Comment: Don't hard code your path.  Use the runtime to determine the correct one.  It will change between installs.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/list try this

Comment: NSString *zipPath = @"/private/var/mobile/Applications/1433FA1B-24FA-4E39-BB57-80569ECBCBAB/Library/Caches/7AD5C113-253D-4F34-8030-612FFE4347E1.zip"; for understand code I put like this in query, in real time I get original path only.

Comment: @square, I try this too, Static path working fine but runtime path not working.

Comment: @square, I place my video file inside /Supporting Files/, Any thing wrong in it ?

Comment: what is the error coming

Comment: Did not get any error. outputPath: /var/mobile/Applications/B4876252-D60D-433F-877E-813773002382/Library/Caches/ests/Regular/, upto this shows exists, but dont know how to get that video. How can I check that file is unziped or not yet ?

Comment: @square, I'm not getting any error. How can I check that file is unziped or not yet ?